# Node-sass related error attempting to setup Zurb Foundation 6 web project on Ubuntu20.04

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, node-sass, zurb-foundation-6

Going to make a personal website and I want to use [Zurb Foundation 6](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/) for the framework.
I am running:
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Node 16.14.0
Npm 8.5.0
yarn 1.22.17

I am following [this](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/starter-projects.html) basic startup guide for the ZURB Foundation template. [img of install instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HniVB.png)
I have tried installing with the Foundation CLI and the manual option both result in [this](https://pastebin.com/0CQtSbju) error.

```
error /home/blake/gitworkspace/BlakeSite/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
```

The error seems to be some consequence of node-sass.
The only lead I could find was [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1) and I don't understand what to do with a bridge file or which one I would need.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node-sass 4.14.1 doesn't support Node 16 https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy. If you need that version, you need to use Node 14